# Debug Linux kernel in a board without GDB

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am totally a fresh on an assignment of developing a driver on a board, which uses a "small" Linux. Every time I make everything and get a ".bin" file on PC and then ftp ".bin" to the board, the system will just work.

Now the problem come. I checked the system, it can not use gdb. So when the system crash, it will just provide a core dump file, which gives messy address info (seems not helping or at least I have no idea how to use this).

Any experienced embedded developer can kindly give some suggestions? How you debugging in your work?

By the way, if the console print crash info includes stack info and  Call Trace, no epc and ra (I just learnt that). Can the epc(crashed address) be found still?

Comment: What means of debug output do you have? Do you have a UART that can be used for printf output? JTAG interface for single-stepping and/or memory inspection?

Comment: @Throwback1986 I have UART to print things to PC console, seems very primitive. And I can not print too many which slow the system

Comment: Debugging using just printk may seem primitive, but it's effective if the code or situation doesn't tolerate breakpoints.  It helps to know C (and the program/system), so that desk-checking the code can catch 99.9% of your bugs.  You have to code methodically (e.g. read the man page and test for all salient return codes) and defensively (e.g. liberal use of assert()).  Fix compiler warnings.  Use a debug_flag variable to control verbosity and which printks are active versus inactive (i.e. don't have every printk active all the time). For panics, enable verbose panic and don't strip symbols.

Comment: There are ways to build the stub part of GDB into a kernel and interact with it over a serial port, but you probably do not need them.  Continue to use the printk's and get the map of your kernel build on the development machine (or disassemble it - look at whatever-whatever-objdump with the -d or -S flag) and compare your failure addresses to that.

Comment: Thanks guys. Can you put reply as an answer so I can choose and close the question please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many kernel developers, including myself, do not use a debugger when developing device drivers. For many years, Linux did not support kernel debugging. Even now, not all CPU architectures support kernel debugging.

One of the easiest things you can do is to use printk to log events to the console. Also, increase the console UART speed. I often use 115200 baud.

The Linux kernel does support kgdb now, for some CPU architectures.

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/index.html

I also highly recommend Linux kernel developers read these two books:

- [Linux Device Drivers](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/), by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, Greg Kroah-Hartman
- [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005658.do), by  Daniel P. Bovet, Marco Cesati

Comment: Thanks man! Is this means, if there are any memory related bugs, it will be extremely hard to find which line of code actually cause the crash? Any tools you may recommended?